# Why can't Windows Server 2008 R2 (during clean install) find ANY device drivers?

Tags: drivers, installation, raid, sata, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (64-bit) onto a (somewhat dated) Dell PowerEdge 1800. I'm am using the bundled Adaptec CERC SATA1.5/6ch RAID controller, and have already created my arrays from my brand new HDDs.

When I get into the installer, it can't find my drives (I expected this much). So, I loaded the SATA drivers that I acquired from Dell's website onto a USB and popped it into the machine. From there, I can browse into the USB drive, and I can see my file structure. However, no drivers are visible from the browse, and the scan turns up nothing.

I unchecked the "Hide drivers that are not compatible..." box and still nothing. I confirmed that the drivers I got are signed, and even tried extracting the contents of the driver packages into a separate folder on the USB and STILL nothing. I even went so far as to load a bunch of non-relevant drivers onto the USB, just to see if Windows would see them. No joy.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any .inf files as part of the drivers? Those are the files that Windows is looking for.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. I unpacked the floppy version of the driver and the only thing I can see that would resemble drivers are dll files. So what, am I just stuck?

Comment: Went and found an old version of the driver from 2004. Confirmed that it had an inf (2 actually). Unpacked it, just to be sure, and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created the RAID at all yet ? You need to create a cluster before attempting to install a system on your drives.

Once done, you can try to use [this driver](http://ftp.dell.com/scsi-raid/LSI-LOGIC_MULTI-DEVICE_A00_R227150.exe) (unpack the .exe first)

This driver is for the 4e/DC. If you have an older LSI controller, you might want to try to load the Win 2k3 64bits driver related to your older controller. If you use an older controller you may need to update it's firmware using a light online system first.

If you have the Adaptec controler, you may want to try [this driver](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=F1MN0&fileId=2731098499&osCode=WS8R2&productCode=poweredge-1800&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SA) instead (unpack the .exe first)

You could also try to boot on Dell's "Systems Build and Update Utility" for your system (For PowerEdge 1800, use [PowerEdge1800 specific disc](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=NF1CT&fileId=2731102793&osCode=WS8R2&productCode=poweredge-1800&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM) , burn to disc or use hardware iso mounting)

Comment: I have a SATA controller, not a SCSI. And yes the arrays are initialized.

That being said, that driver is one of the ones I loaded onto the flash drive just to check.

Comment: Please read second half of the answer.

Comment: The adaptec driver is supported by Dell for this model and OS. You can see that here: 
http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=0MNF6
We previously had Server 2003 working on this machine, if that helps.
The bigger issue I'm having is that Windows installation can't see any drivers at all, not that the controller isn't working.

Comment: Didn't load your edit before I sent that last comment. Either way, thanks for being condescending. Would not go to a "superuser" forum if I didn't know how to find a driver. You could also try reading my entire question to see that the issue is more complicated.

Comment: I'm sorry but the link you provided is to drivers for Server 2008, not 2008 R2. Drivers from 2008 and 2008 R2 are rarely compatible. I did some further digging myself and, while Server 2008 R2 is supported by Dell for the PowerEdge 1800, they do not provide any Server 2008 R2 drivers for your SATA card. EDIT: corrected mistake regarding above link.